# Getting data from xml file and comparing it to a text file

Tags: c#, xml, streamreader, system.io.file

So I have two files: a mot file and an xml file. What I need to do with these files is to read data from the xml file and compare it to the mot file if it exists. That's the general idea.

> Before anything else, for those who are unfamiliar with what a mot
> file is (I don't also have much knowledge about it, just the basics)...
> [(From Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SREC_(file_format)) A mot file (or a Motorola S-Record
> file) is a file format that conveys binary information in ASCII Hex text form.
> [(from another source)](http://www.amelek.gda.pl/avr/uisp/srecord.htm) An S-record file consists of a
> sequence of specially formatted ASCII character strings. An S-record
> will be less than or equal to 78 bytes in length.
>
> The format of a S-Record is:
> S | Type | Record Length | Address (starting address) | Data | Checksum
> *(e.g. S21404200047524D5354524D0000801410AA5AA555F9)
>
> ([parsed] S2  14  042000  47524D5354524D0000801410AA5AA555  F9)*

The specific idea is that I have data AA BB CC DD and so on allocated in addresses 0x042000 ~ 0x04200F. What’s written in the xml would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<data-set xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<record>
  <File name="Test.mot">
    <Address id="042000">
    <Data>AA</Data>
  </Address>
  </File>
</record>
<record>
  <File name="Test.mot">
    <Address id="042001">
      <Data>BB CC DD</Data>
    </Address>
  </File>
</record>
<record>
  <File name="Test.mot">
    <Address id="042004">
      <Data>EE FF</Data>
    </Address>
  </File>
</record>
```

Then the program would get the data and address from he XML and search the .mot file for any hits. So if a mot file has a record `S214042000AABBCCDDEEFF01234567891A2B3C4D5EF9`, then this is supposed to bring a match with what's in the xml. Result to true, or 1. If anything in the xml doesn't have a match, then it would return with false or 0.

The problem now would be I’m not well-versed with C# much less with XML although I did have a tiny bit of experience with both. I initially thought it would be something like this:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("Test.mot"))
{
     String line =String.Empty;
     while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
     {
         if (line.Contains("042004") & line.Contains("EE FF"))
         {
             Console.WriteLine("Success");
         }
         else
         {
             Console.WriteLine("Failure");
         }
     }
}
```

But obviously, it didn't result with what I expected. And `Failure` keeps popping up. Am I right to use `StreamReader` to read the .mot file? And with regards to the XML file, will `XMLDocument` work? How do I get data from the xml and compare it with the .mot file? Could someone walk me through how to get this done or provide guides how to properly start with this.

Let me know if I'm not clear on anything.

EDIT:

I thought of an idea. I'm not sure if it's doable, though. Let's say the program will read the mot S-Record file, and it will identify the type of the record. From there every record line listed in the file would be broken down as shown in the sample below:

```
sample record line: "S214042000AABBCCDDEEFF01234567891A2B3C4D5EF9"  
S2 - type w/c means there would be a 3-byte address  
14 - record length  
F9 - checksum  
042000 - AA  
042001 - BB  
042002 - CC  
042003 - DD  
...  
04200F - 5E
```

With this new list, I think or I hope it would be easier for the program to use the data in the XML to locate it in the mot file.

Tell me if this will work, or if there are any alternatives.

Comment: Hi, you seem to be using a bitwise operand (&) in your condition. Have you tried using the logical operand (&&)? if (line.Contains("042004") && line.Contains("EE FF"))

Comment: I'm an expert with both Motorola format (40 years) and XML.  My first question is what is the number of bytes of data?  My first though is to create a byte[] array and put one format into the array.  Then compare the 2nd  format against byte[].  I'm not sure what to so with the unused memory locations in the arrays.  It looks like you have Morotorola S2 format (not S3 or S4) which would mean you have a small device less than 64K.  The S2 format my not be sorted in increasing memory locations.

Comment: @jdweng the number of bytes would depend on the s-type. the sample i showed was just with s2 but i also have s1 and s3 format with me to use.

Comment: Normally I do a 2 passes on the data.  The first is to get the range of addresses.  Then I create a byte[] array which is the size of the range of address with all values set to zero (sometimes FF).  Then fill the array from one format. Then I either compare the 2nd format to first on the fly, or create a 2nd byte[] and fill with 2nd format the compare the 2 byte[].  Not sure in this case which is the best method with info provided.

Comment: I'm not sure if I get it but do you mean that within the program, the program would somehow compute for the range of address with only the extracted address (e.g. 042000) from the xml?  So if the corresponding data to that address is "AA BB" which has two bytes then the range of address would be 042000  042001. What do you mean by filling the array from one format? Sorry if I'm not quick to understand your explanations. Could you provide a sample of the process? And please let me know if I failed to provide some other essential information. Thanks

Comment: @jdweng I edited a bit of the post, added some more info. Might clear some confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me when i'm wrong as it is full of assumptions:

the XML only gives the starting values of the data package under the mot file:

```
          ||||||||||||
S214042000AABBCCDDEEFF01234567891A2B3C4D5EF9
          AABBCCDDEEFF
```

You could read out the xml and place each record in a record class

```
public class Record
{
    string FileName{get;set;}
    string Id {get;set;}
    string Data {get;set;}
    public Record(){} //default constructor
}
```

with the XmlDocument class you could read out the xml.

something like:

```
var document = new XmlDocument();
document.LoadXml("your.xml");

var records = document.SelectNodes("record");
var recordList = new List<Record>();
foreach(var r in records)
{
    var file = r.SelectSingleNode("file");
    var fileName = file.Attributes["name"].Value;
    var address = file.SelectSingleNode("Address");
    var id = address.Attributes["id"].Value;
    var data = address.SelectSingleNode("Data").InnerText.Replace(" ", "");

    recordList.Add(new Record{FileName = fileName, Id = id, Data = data});
}
```

Afterwards you can then readout everyline of the mot file by position:
since the location of the 042000 always be the 5 - 10 character

```
var fn = "Test.mot";
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fn))
{    
     var record = recordList.Single(r=> r.FileName);
     String line =String.Empty;
     while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
     {        

         if (line.SubString(4,6) == record.Id && line.SubString(10, record.Data.Length) == record.Data)
         {
             Console.WriteLine("Success");
         }
         else
         {
             Console.WriteLine("Failure");
         }
     }
}
```

Let me know if it helped you out a bit

Comment: Schuere : You are correct that both formats only give the start address and the data bytes which number can vary.  The number of bytes in the two formats (XML and Mot S) may not have the records sizes blocked the same.  And the memory range can be huge.  Using a Record class may be a good idea, but I can't tell with limited info right now.  I've written code in the past using records, but made sure the records started on an boundary that was a multiple of 2 and filled unused location with fixed data.

Comment: @Schuere, hello I think this will work if the format for the record if fixed. and as jdweng said, the formats may not be in the same in all cases. plus what troubles me is that what if in a line there's a duplicate of the record I'm trying to locate (e.g. there are two "2A"s in one record line)